# Pandas - Count correlated events on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, data-science

I would like to create DataFrame, possibly sparse, which measure the correlations between users. Here, my definition of correlation between `user_1` and `user_2` is the number of times they both performed the same `action` on the same day.

I will try to explain myself better using an example. Suppose I have the following Dataframe:

```
date    action  user
6   2019-05-05  b   user_3
9   2019-05-05  b   user_2
1   2019-05-06  b   user_2
5   2019-05-06  a   user_1
0   2019-05-07  b   user_3
7   2019-05-07  a   user_2
8   2019-05-07  a   user_1
2   2019-05-08  c   user_2
4   2019-05-08  c   user_1
3   2019-05-09  c   user_3
```

which can be generated using this snippet:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(12)
users = np.random.choice(['user_1', 'user_2', 'user_3'], size=10)
actions = np.random.choice(['a', 'b', 'c'], size=10)
date = np.random.choice(pd.date_range(start='2019-05-05', end='2019-05-10', freq='D'), size=10)

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(date=date, action=actions, user=users))
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df = df.sort_values('date')
```

The correlation between `user_1` and `user_2` is `2` since they both performed action `a` on the day `07` and action `c` on day `08`. The correlation between `user_2` and `user_3` is `1` because they performed action `b` on day `05`. All the rest is `NaN`. They output DataFrame I'm seeking is the following:

```
        user_1  user_2  user_3
user_1  NaN     NaN     NaN
user_2  2.0     NaN     NaN
user_3  NaN     1.0     NaN
```

---

My inefficient way of creating this DataFrame is the following:

```
from itertools import combinations
df_result = pd.DataFrame(columns=['user_1', 'user_2', 'user_3'],
                         index=['user_1', 'user_2', 'user_3'], dtype=np.float64)    

for index, group in df.groupby(['date', 'action']):
    for x, y in combinations(list(group.user.values), 2):
        if np.isnan(df_result.loc[x,y]):
            df_result.loc[x, y] = 1
        else:
            df_result.loc[x, y] = df_result.loc[x, y] + 1
```

The problem with this approach is being way to slow in my use-case.

Comment: how big is your dataframe?

Comment: roughly 200k different users and a few billions of rows in the DataFrame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one potential approach, using [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.merge.html), to self-join on `date` and `action`. Then use [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html), to filter out where user is equal on both sides and finally [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) for the output.

```
df_corr = (df.merge(df, on=['date', 'action'])
           .query('user_x != user_y')
           .pivot_table(index='user_x', columns='user_y', aggfunc='size'))
```

[out]

```
user_y  user_1  user_2  user_3
user_x                        
user_1     NaN     2.0     NaN
user_2     2.0     NaN     1.0
user_3     NaN     1.0     NaN
```

---

If showing the lower triangle of the correlation matrix only is a requirement, you can `NaN` out the upper section using:

```
mask = np.triu_indices_from(df_corr)
df_corr.values[mask] = np.nan
```

[out]

```
user_y  user_1  user_2  user_3
user_x                        
user_1     NaN     NaN     NaN
user_2     2.0     NaN     NaN
user_3     NaN     1.0     NaN
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really like your approach. I do not need to take care of the lower triangle (and actually nether of the diagonal, so I skipped the query). I'm facing a `ValueError: Unstacked DataFrame is too big, causing int32 overflow` error due to the `pivot_table`. I'm trying to understand if what I would like to obtain is doable using RAM only.

Comment: My secret hope was that pandas would have managed the memory by using sparse representation, but I was probably too optimistic

Comment: Yeh, I just seen the size of your data after I posted this... it's pretty huge! Probably needs another approach to process that amount of data in that way

Comment: I completely agree with you, I will probably try with a graph representation. Still, your answer is pretty much on the spot for reasonably sized data (for the records 10x improvement in performance on a dummy dataset)